# Error with reading dataframe while submitting batch job through Juliahub

Tags: julia, cloud, development-environment

I am trying to submit a batch job through JuliaHub. I am trying to read the dataset using the full path to the file :

```
df = CSV.read("/home/jrun/data/code/ECMO_UMMC/UFH_PEDS_PK.csv",DataFrame)
```

however, the job fails and it says the following in he job log:

```
Error running user code
Timestamp: 23 Dec 2023, 6:28 AM-1703330919396
Worker: jr-da92suprxy-x62n4, id: 1
Thread: 1
Module: Main.JuliaRunJob
Level: Error
Group: master_startup
Exception:
LoadError: ArgumentError: "/home/jrun/data/code/ECMO_UMMC/UFH_PEDS_PK.csv" is not a valid file or doesn't exist
```

When I try to upload the file from the REPL, I do not encounter an issue. I am not sure why the dataset cannot be read from the batch job submission.

Any help to solve this problem is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you need to understand your HPC environment, specifically what file systems are available on the batch nodes. you might wanna contact JuliaHub support.